# Adding Node to exisitng documents mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to update the existing document with one extra field as a new requirement in DB needs that

**Existing field**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62a8ad644035e93c7ff24607"
  },
  "user_name": "demo2@devia.com",
  "password": "1234",
  "college_id": {
    "$oid": "628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13"
  },
  "basic_details": {
    "first_name": "ghgh",
    "middle_name": "",
    "last_name": "gh",
    "email": "demo2@devia.com",
    "mobile_number": 1234567890
  },
  "address_details": {
    "country": {
      "country_id": {
        "$oid": "623012f9683f8fb7bd213c36"
      },
      "country_code": "IN"
    },
    "state": {
      "state_id": {
        "$oid": "623013d9683f8fb7bd2381c4"
      },
      "state_code": "MP"
    },
    "city": {
      "city_id": {
        "$oid": "6230139f683f8fb7bd21f1a9"
      },
      "city_name": "Akodia"
    },
    "address_line1": "",
    "address_line2": "",
    "pincode": ""
  },
  "is_verify": false,
  "last_accessed": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1655221604144"
    }
  },
  "created_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1655221604144"
    }
  },
  "course_details": {}
}]
```

**Needs to update all fields**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62bf2cf2a8c782741bbcc398"
  },
  "user_name": "a@exaple.com",
  "password": "$2b$12$NgLNYm5jUBmFUq.w15.qCO35GiTJX09jAnOpoGuPt9G7GNuOkVN7K",
  "college_id": {
    "$oid": "628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13"
  },
  "basic_details": {
    "email": "a@example.com",
    "mobile_number": "9898989898",
    "first_name": "Fahim",
    "middle_name": "",
    "last_name": "Ashhab",
    "nationality": "Antiguans",
    "date_of_birth": "2003-02-04",
    "admission_year": "2022-23",
    "gender": "Male",
    "category": "General",
    "para_ability": {
      "is_disable": false,
      "name_of_disability": ""
    }
  },
  "address_details": {
    "communication_address": {
      "country": {
        "country_id": {
          "$oid": "623012f9683f8fb7bd213c36"
        },
        "country_code": "IN"
      },
      "state": {
        "state_id": {
          "$oid": "623013d9683f8fb7bd2380ef"
        },
        "state_code": "AP"
      },
      "city": {
        "city_id": {
          "$oid": "6230139f683f8fb7bd21ebc8"
        },
        "city_name": "Akasahebpet"
      },
      "address_line1": "jjkjk",
      "address_line2": "uiui",
      "pincode": "989898"
    }
  },
  "is_verify": true,
  "last_accessed": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1656696050670"
    }
  },
  "created_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1656696050670"
    }
  },
  "allocate_to_counselor": {
    "counselor_id": {
      "$oid": "62bfd13a5ce8a398ad101bd7"
    },
    "counselor_name": "test",
    "last_update": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1656817948401"
      }
    }
  },
  "course_details": {
    "BSc": {
      "course_id": {
        "$oid": "628e03d94e22276b98231407"
      },
      "course_name": "BSc",
      "application_id": {
        "$oid": "62bf2cf2a8c782741bbcc399"
      },
      "status": "Incomplete",
      "specs": [
        {
          "spec_name": "Physician Assistant",
          "is_activated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}]
```

**Query Tried nothing is happening**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"address_details.country": {$exists:true}}},
{$set:{address_details:{communication_address:"$address_details"}}}
])
```

**2nd Query Tried didn't go through**

```
db.studentsPrimaryDetails.updateMany({
    "address_details.communication_address": {"$exist":false}},
    {$set: {"address_details.communication_address":"$address_details"}})
```

The desired result needs to be
*from this*

```json
"address_details": {
    "country": {
      "country_id": {
        "$oid": "623012f9683f8fb7bd213c36"
      },
      "country_code": "IN"
    },
    "state": {
      "state_id": {
        "$oid": "623013d9683f8fb7bd2381c4"
      },
      "state_code": "MP"
    },
    "city": {
      "city_id": {
        "$oid": "6230139f683f8fb7bd21f1a9"
      },
      "city_name": "Akodia"
    },
    "address_line1": "",
    "address_line2": "",
    "pincode": ""
  }
```

*to this*

```
  "address_details": {
    "communication_address": {
      "country": {
        "country_id": {
          "$oid": "623012f9683f8fb7bd213c36"
        },
        "country_code": "IN"
      },
      "state": {
        "state_id": {
          "$oid": "623013d9683f8fb7bd2380ef"
        },
        "state_code": "AP"
      },
      "city": {
        "city_id": {
          "$oid": "6230139f683f8fb7bd21ebc8"
        },
        "city_name": "Akasahebpet"
      },
      "address_line1": "jjkjk",
      "address_line2": "uiui",
      "pincode": "989898"
    }
  }
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Edit :

Desired full output

````
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62bf2cf2a8c782741bbcc398"
  },
  "user_name": "a@example.com",
  "password": "12345678",
  "college_id": {
    "$oid": "628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13"
  },
  "basic_details": {
    "email": "a@example.com",
    "mobile_number": "9898989898",
    "first_name": "Fahim",
    "middle_name": "",
    "last_name": "Ashhab",
    "nationality": "Antiguans",
    "date_of_birth": "2003-02-04",
    "admission_year": "2022-23",
    "gender": "Male",
    "category": "General",
    "para_ability": {
      "is_disable": false,
      "name_of_disability": ""
    }
  },
  "address_details": {
    "communication_address": {
      "country": {
        "country_id": {
          "$oid": "623012f9683f8fb7bd213c36"
        },
        "country_code": "IN"
      },
      "state": {
        "state_id": {
          "$oid": "623013d9683f8fb7bd2380ef"
        },
        "state_code": "AP"
      },
      "city": {
        "city_id": {
          "$oid": "6230139f683f8fb7bd21ebc8"
        },
        "city_name": "Akasahebpet"
      },
      "address_line1": "jjkjk",
      "address_line2": "uiui",
      "pincode": "989898"
    }
  },
  "is_verify": true,
  "last_accessed": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1656696050670"
    }
  },
  "created_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1656696050670"
    }
  },
  "allocate_to_counselor": {
    "counselor_id": {
      "$oid": "62bfd13a5ce8a398ad101bd7"
    },
    "counselor_name": "viru chaudhary",
    "last_update": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1656817948401"
      }
    }
  },
  "course_details": {
    "BSc": {
      "course_id": {
        "$oid": "628e03d94e22276b98231407"
      },
      "course_name": "BSc",
      "application_id": {
        "$oid": "62bf2cf2a8c782741bbcc399"
      },
      "status": "Incomplete",
      "specs": [
        {
          "spec_name": "Physician Assistant",
          "is_activated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

1. Use `$exists` instead of `$exist`
2. Use pipeline in order to be able to `$set` the value from another fields' value

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {"address_details.communication_address": {$exists: false}},
  [{$set: {address_detailsB: {communication_address: "$address_details"}}},
   {$set: {
     address_details: "$address_detailsB",
     address_detailsB: "$$REMOVE"}
   }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pXSRjrOWfNw)

The aggregation query that you first tried, does not not update the db, it only returns data. In order to use it as an updater you need to add a `$merge` step.